# Form to mail attachment

Tags: php, forms, attachment

I'm trying to mail a form with attachment (picture).
But I can't get it to work.
I think I have tried almost everything, exept the one thing that will make it work :)
And search all of google and youtube.

I get the picture, but not any username or city.

Can somebody please help me.
 Dont know what i'm doing wrong or missing?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['terms'])){
  $email_to = "mail@mail.com";
  $email_subject = "Subject";
  $user = $_POST['user']; // required
  $city = $_POST['city']; // required

  /*********Creating Uniqid Session*******/

  $txtSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

  $headers = "";
  $headers .= "From: ".$_POST["fieldFormName"]."<".$_POST["fieldFormEmail"].">\nReply-To: ".$_POST["fieldFormEmail"]."";

  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$txtSid."\"\n\n";
  $headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

  $headers .= "--".$txtSid."\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
  $headers .= $email_message."\n\n";

  /***********Email Attachment************/
  if($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] != "")
  {
    $txtFilesName = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"];
    $txtContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"]))); 
    $headers .= "--".$txtSid."\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$txtFilesName."\"\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$txtFilesName."\"\n\n";
    $headers .= $txtContent."\n\n";
  }


  $email_message = "Message.\n\n";

  function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
  }

  $email_message .= "User: ".clean_string($user)."\n";
  $email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($city)."\n";

  // Send
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
}else{
  echo "You need to accept our terms";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PHPMailer, it is way more easy to be used than creating your own html/headers/etc.

Comment: I'm following the simple example at github.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Keep getting this error:
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

But the email is being sent to the mail...

The SMPT info is correct.. Got it from my servers support.

Got any idea?

Comment: Either update your question with some new code or start a new question. SMTP connect() error raises thequestion for me that your smtp Server is incorrect.. Maybe also provide the details provider from your support team.

Comment: I have posted a new question with my code here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168643/phpmailer-help-getting-smtp-error-but-mail-is-send

Thanks.